# linux du command source code

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Where I can find the source code for `du` and other Linux utilities?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is with the [GNU CoreUtils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package.

Answer (score 13):

David is right.  You can start with the entry point, [du.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/du.c), in Savannah.  Also, since it's free software under the GPL, you can also get it from your GNU/Linux distribution.  E.g., on Debian or Ubuntu you can generally just do:

```
apt-get source coreutils
```

to get the source for the version installed.

---

(EDIT by Novelocrat)

For other commands, to find out what package they're in, you can say

```
dpkg -S `which command`
```

`which command` will tell you the full path to that command, and `dpkg -S filename` will tell you what package provides a file. Then you can run `apt-get source packagename` to get its source code.

Comment: +1 for `du.c`. It spared me of downloading the entire package