# Linux- C program

Tags: c, linux

I have recently(yesterday) started trying to learn linux and to program in this os. Now, one interesting and probably easy problem I came across while surfing the net was something like this:

Consider a C program that takes a directory as an argument in the command line and calculates the sum of all the files' dimensions that are in the directory's tree.

Now, due to the fact that I've been doing a lot of reading and researching in a short matter of time, all my knowledge is piled up in my brian creating a cloud of confusion. If anyone could help me with the code, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: you did not post or provide a link to said code.

Comment: @ron Well, there is no code yet, that's the reason I came here.

Comment: One of the nice things about unix is it encourages a tool based approach. So assuming I understand what you mean by `sum of all the files dimensions` you can do this by combining 2 existing tools. The first is `find` which walks directory trees, and the second is `awk` which can add up numbers for you. With this I get `find STARTDIR -type f -printf "%s\n" | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'` and no C code to write at all.

Comment: dimensions meaning "size in blocks or bytes" or "length of filename" or "width and height of a picture"? If this is a question from a textbook, class, or online tutorial, please paste the exact text of the question here.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick It reffers to "size in blocks or bytes"

Comment: Can you edit your question and say what is exactly what is causing you confusion?

Comment: your initial wording was confusing, it seems you are asking for help to write C code `that takes a directory as an argument in the command line and calculates the sum of all the files' dimensions that are in the directory's tree`.  Which is most likely why your post has been moved to stackoverflow, it was not clear what you were asking as was written & posted in the linux forum.  Per your question you are not really trying to learn linux, you are wanting to learn  C programming.

Comment: There is no easy answer to that question. Even if you knew how to write this program, how would you deal with hardlinks to files? How about hardlinks to directories?

Comment: @Emyeminescu did any of the answers given to you help you solve your problem? If so, please consider marking one answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are asking is a basic task.  It can be done in linux but can also be done in microsoft windows with minor code tweaks if you are writing a program in C or C++.   you would be writing code, which is sort of at a lower level compared to other ways of doing it, to accomplish what you want.

However you don't need to write a program C, which then requires you to compile it into an executable.  Because what you are asking is a basic task, you might be able to do it with a bash shell script which would be linux specific.  And if you wanted to do this in Windows then you would write a .bat file which is either the DOS scripting language, or Windows Powershell.  I am not that familiar with Windows, i only mention it to help give you a general understanding for "all the knowledge piled up in your brain creating a cloud of confusion".

There is the windirstat program which runs under Microsoft Windows, can get it free from sourceforge and I think it does mostly what you are asking.  I am not sure if you can get source code for it.

For linux there is `kdirstat` and that you can get the source code for from
http://kdirstat.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/kdirstat/
you can download it as GNU tarball.
Look at how that program is written, which is C++ as you'll see a bunch of .cpp files.  That would be a good template to work off of, and you can see what libraries they are using to accomplish file system functions.  There are 21 .cpp files, look at the file `kdirstatmain.cpp` first.
For C/C++ code the start of execution is with the function `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Regarding accomplishing this task with a bash shell script in linux, the best i can tell you is web search on bash shell scripting for linux.

And in linux to `calculate the sum of all the files' dimensions that are in the directory's tree` we can quickly do that at the linux prompt with the `du -sh .` command.  In linux at the prompt do `man du` so read about the *disk usage* command.  And then consider looking for the source code for `du` to use it as a template, and work off how they implemented du to learn and then modify their ways to meet your needs.

[linux du command source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264843/linux-du-command-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

Use `opendir(3)` to "open" the directory. Since you are interested in learning how to program in GNU/Linux, start by typing `man opendir` in the terminal to read how this function works. The `(3)` in `opendir(3)` means that the help for this function can be found in the section 3 of the manpages. Notice, at the top of the page, that the manpage tells you which `#include`s you'll need.

If everything goes right, `opendir(3)` will return a `DIR*` object. To know which files or subdirectories it contains, you use this object with `readdir(3)`. This should return a pointer of type `struct dirent*`. You can heck the manual pages for details on the fields of this structure, but the most important for you will probably be `d_type` and `d_name`. A second call to this function will return the next entry. When it returns `NULL`, that either means you have read all files or an error occurred. To know which happened, you should check `errno`.

Here's a short example that list all entries in `/tmp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    dir = opendir("/tmp");
    /* should check if dir != NULL */

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        printf("Found %s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
    /* You may want to check errno here to see if readdir returned
     * NULL because all files were read or because of some error;
     * but this is beyond the purposes of my example.
     */

    closedir(dir);

    return 0;
}
```

Now you have to process each entry. If it is a directory, you have to descend into it an read its contents. A recursive function will probably help you here. If it is a file, then you have at least two options:

1. Open it with `fopen(3)`, then use `fseek(3)` to seek the end of file. Use the return value of `fseek(3)` to calculate the size of the file in bytes;
2. Use `stat(2)` to get a structure with information on the file. Do not confuse it with `stat(1)`. If you simply type `man stat`, you'll get information about the latter. To force `man` to read from section 2, type `man 2 stat` in the command line.

The first approach is certainly simpler. The second will require you to do a bit of reading on how `stat(2)` works. My advice: you should do it. Not only because it's more in the lines of Linux, but also because it gives you information that `fseek(3)` doesn't give. For instance, you can use `stat(2)` to see not only how many bytes the file contains, but how many bytes it occupies in the disk (like `du` does).

While reading the directory, you may stumble on other types of entries other than files and directories. `stat(2)` will probably help you figure the sizes of them as well. But you may want to simply ignore them for now.